# How to have obstacles on separate nav mesh layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem with nav mesh obstacles. Basically, I have a red enemy and a blue enemy. I want red enemies to be affected by red walls, and blue enemies to be affected by blue walls. That's it, very simple.
I have downloaded the [NavMeshComponents](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents) and I am using that.

I have all the different layers set up correctly. I have a red agent and a blue agent, with each surface spcifically using those.
Howveer, when I make a NavMeshObstacle, and put it on a red wall layer, it bakes into the blue nav mesh as well.

How can I make the red nav mesh surface not be affected by the blue wall?